# multiple workers and multiple queues on celery django daemon

Tags: django, celery, daemon, django-celery, celeryd

I am using celery-django to queue tasks on my site backend.
I am trying to create a setup where I have two queues named "low" and "high" and two workers W1 and W2.
I want them to consume the tasks from the queue in the following way:

**W1 <-- low, high**

**W2  <-- high**

Normally it can be done like this.

Open terminal 1 and enter 
    $`celery worker -n W1 -Q low,high`

Open terminal 2 and enter 
    $`celery worker -n W2 -Q high`

However I am trying to do the same via **celeryd daemon**.

I am following the steps given in the link: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-configuration
But the available options don't seem enough to fit the requirement.

Please help me with some configs that I am unaware of which could make it possible. I would prefer not to run multiple daemons or use additional tools like supervisord unless really necessary (Maybe you could advice me on this as well).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `CELERYD_OPTS` option passing -Q parameter similar to those examples from [Celery reference](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html):

```
# Advanced example starting 10 workers in the background:
#   * Three of the workers processes the images and video queue
#   * Two of the workers processes the data queue with loglevel DEBUG
#   * the rest processes the default' queue.
$ celery multi start 10 -l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data
    -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG

# You can show the commands necessary to start the workers with
# the 'show' command:
$ celery multi show 10 -l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data
    -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG
```

Comment: If I name my nodes like `CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5"` instead of using `-c 4` can I still use the syntax of `-Q:1-3`?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify multiple nodes in CELERY_NODES and pass node names to CELERYD_OPTS arguments, for example:

```
CELERY_NODES="W1 W2"
CELERYD_OPTS="-Q:W1 low,high -Q:W2 high"
```